# Grails validation goes into a loop and never breaks

Tags: grails, constraints, grails-orm

I have a class User which has a validation rule like:

```
def readyUserCount = User.createCriteria().count({
    eq('userStatus',UserStatus.Ready)                   
})
if(100 > readyUserCount){
    return true
}
```

When validated, it will count existing rows in the DB. The issue is when I update a object, it will trigger validation, validation will trigger flush, flush will trigger validation, validation will trigger flush, and never break up. (If I'm inserting instead of updating this issue does not occur). Can anyone help me?

Comment: How is statement called?  Is it in the static constraints or on a beforeUpdate interceptor or somewhere else?

Comment: it's in the static constraints and the save() action is called in a withNewSession() block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`withNewSession()`](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/withNewSession.html):

```
def count = User.withNewSession{ User.countByUserStatus(UserStatus.Ready) }
```

Comment: thx, it works. And it also works if i call save without validation .save(validate:false).

Comment: Well, I didn't know if validator is not called or its value just discarded with `validate: false`. Thanks :)

Comment: ^_^, you are right, validator is not called. As I prefer not start a new session in one request. and the validator can be trigger manually by call validate()

Comment: I want to know why this happened ? is it a bug of grails?

Comment: Sorry, what - this happened? Flush loop? Any dynamic finder or `Criteria` trigger a flush() in Grails for every object that might be affected by the criteria. That's why we need a new session. And come on, it's just a session per `save()` - I hope users don't `save()` too often.

Comment: User.withTransaction {
  user.save()
}                                                                will trigger flush loop, but if call in controller, no this issue. so what's the reason

Comment: I seem to have explained the flush reason.

Comment: I know User.countByUserStatus(UserStatus.Ready) will trigger session flush, and your walkaroud User.withNewSession will start a new session  then User.countByUserStatus(UserStatus.Ready) will not trigger session flush. And I want to know what's the different between call user.save() in controller and can User.withTransaction { user.save() } in other place such as filter.

Comment: Oh, now I see what you mean. No idea. And a good topic for another question/maillist discussion.